# Relation between $y=Ax_1$ and $y=WAx_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question. Is there any relation between the following linear equations?
$$y=Ax_1 \ \ \text{ and} \ \  y=WAx_2$$
W is diagonal square invertable matrix, A is an mxn matrix with $n>m$.

I mean, can we get $x_2$ if we have the solution to the first equation and $W$?
I just want to know the solution of the second equation if we know the solution to the first equation. Here is my approach to solve this: The solution to the first equation is a solution that satisfy y=Ax (any solution) and any combination of null space basis of the matrix A. I know that multiplying by W does not change the null space, so, I think that only the basic solution will be affected by W. I just want to know this effect.

Comment: Please add some further details to the question. What motivated you to consider this problem? Did you consider any special cases to see if that provided any insight? At what point precisely were you unable to continue your investigation into the problem?

Comment: I just want to know the solution of the second equation if we know the solution to the first equation. Here is my approach to solve this:
The solution to the first equation is an solution that satisfy $y=Ax$ (any solution) and any combination of null space basis of the matrix $A$. I know that multiplying by $W$ does not change the null space, so, I think that only the basic solution will be affected by $W$. I just want to know  this effect.
Thanks

Comment: Very nice, you should add this to the question by editting! Did you consider writing the second equation in the form $W^{-1}y=Ax_2$?

Comment: Yes, I did. But what we can get from writing the first equation as $W^-1 y=Ax_2$ ??
We still have the same problem. The problem is with $A$ because $A$ is not invertable.

Comment: If you improve the question by editting to include the additional information you have come upon, the chances of someone answering will be much higher.

Comment: How did you get $x_1$? If you got it from e.g. an LU-decomposition of $A$, just use the same LU-decomposition to solve for the right hand side $W^{-1}y$.

Comment: May one assume that A is surjective?

Comment: I don't have $x_1$, I just have a solution set of $x_1$ which can be written as $x_1=x_p+N$, where: $x_p$ is any solution that satisfy the equation $y=Ax$, and  $N \in Null(A)$. I just know that multiplying by $W$ will not affect the solution part correspond to $Null(A)$, but it will affect $x_p$. I want to find what will be the effect on $x_p$. Also, I am not sure if $A$ is surjective (I'm not sure what surjective is), I know for sure that the system is underdetermined.